# Seeking a test for detecting a parameter to a method is a literal array

Tags: arrays, vba, variant

I have a need to determine if an array passed to a method is a variable or a literal array

1. Pass by variable

```
Dim myA as Variant
myA = array(1,2,3,4,5)
myMethod myA
```

verses
2. Pass by literal array

```
myMethod Array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I have looked at the variant VT type and the ffeatures flags of the safearray struct for both types of parameter and in both cases I get a VT of &H 0880 and ffeatures of &H200C.  This means at present I can't differentiate between MyA and Array(1,2,3,4,5).

The reason for asking this question is that I am trying to create a class that persists a reference to an Array.  With myA this is no problem as the array exists independently of the class.  However with Array(1,2,3,4,5) the array is transient, it no longer exists once the method returns, so in this case I'd need to make a copy of the array.

I'd appreciate pointers as to where I should be looking next.

Comment: You could use the `IsArray` function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isarray-function

Comment: @CHill60 That doesn't seem to be a useful response.  Both parameters are arrays.  Its just the way in which they are presented as a parameter which is different.

Comment: good point - I misread the question

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet found a solution by testing the input variables.

However I found that if I applied a safearray lock to the input array then in the case of the literal Array it is not destroyed after exiting the method.

This action does mean that a non literal external array cannot be resized until I remove the lock, but I think this is an acceptable trade off.